CefSharp.Offscreen could not load CefSharp assembly on runtime
I cannot get CefSharp.Offscreen to work in my .NET7 web api project. Strangely the exact same code works absolutely fine when I use it in a .NET7 console app. When I launch the web app I get the following error:
Could not load file or assembly '<path>\bin\deploy\net7.0\publish\runtimes\win-x64\lib\netcoreapp3.1\CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'. The specified module could not be found

So of course I checked and the .dll file is there and can be read by the application (tested through a File.Exists(...)). I already tried reinstalling the CefSharp.Common.NETCore Nuget.
I publish my application through the dotnet publish command in a PowerShell script as:
dotnet publish "$project\$project.csproj" -p:PublishProfile=publish-$configuration --framework net7.0 --output "$project\bin\deploy\net7.0\publish"
I read about potentially missing Visual C++ Redistributable packages, so I downloaded the latest from here, but that was already installed through my Visual Studio 17.8.6 IDE.

Copying dependencies.  If that doesn't help then use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see the program searching for the missing DLL.

Try adding --runtime win-x64 --no-self-contained to your publish command

@amaitland That is what I ended up doing. I don't get why and I had to fix some other issues that were triggered because of the additional parameter, but at least it solved it. Thanks!

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4486#discussioncomment-5737425
